# Powershell error moving files on network drive

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a simple script I have been using to organize downloaded files into folders.  I have had 2 issues I'm trying to overcome.

1. The script won't run from a mapped network drive (M:)
2. Running the script inside ISE works sometimes but give errors

Here's the code:

```
cls
cd M:\!Pool
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy ByPass
Move-Item -Path ".\*Video\*" -Destination ".\\Video"
Move-Item -Path ".\*Club\*" -Destination ".\\Club" -Exclude *DanceClub*
Move-Item -Path ".\\Express Audio\*" -Destination ".\\Express Audio"
Move-Item -Path ".\\Alternative\*" -Destination ".\\Alternative"
Move-Item -Path ".\\Country Radio\*" -Destination ".\\Country"
Move-Item -Path ".\\Contemporary Christian\*" -Destination ".\\Contemporary Christian"
Move-Item -Path ".\*Dance Radio\*" -Destination ".\\Dance Radio"
Move-Item -Path ".\*Mainstream Radio\*" -Destination ".\\Mainstream Radio"
Move-Item -Path ".\\Modern Rock\*" -Destination ".\\Modern Rock"
Move-Item -Path ".\\Rhythm Radio\*" -Destination ".\\Rhythm Radio"
Move-Item -Path ".\\Urban\*" -Destination ".\\Urban"
Move-Item -Path ".\\Caribbean\*" -Destination ".\\Caribbean"
Move-Item -Path ".\*Latin\*" -Destination ".\\Latin" -Exclude *Caribbean*
```

- **Details

1. Double-clicking on the script launches it and the PS window appears for a short time, no files move
2. Opening in ISE and running it manually moves some files sometimes but always gives the error for each line:

> Move-Item : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
> At line:1 char:1

Here's the PSVersion info just in case...

```
> Name                           Value
> \----                           -----
> PSVersion                      5.1.19041.2364
> PSEdition                      Desktop
> PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
> BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.2364
> CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
> WSManStackVersion              3.0
> PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
> SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

I know this is a very simple script and I could likely do it much better.  I'm open to suggestions and even have a batch file I use to move other files folders around better since I haven't been able to get these to work well yet.

Thanks for the help, on my 1st post (long time lurker).

Comment: Have you tried providing the FQDN rather?

Comment: `M:!Pool` --> `M:\Pool`

Comment: @Theo - Good eye. Copy/Paste error.  There is a backslash in the script.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - I haven't since this is on a non-domain connection.